# Problemas ao referenciar arquivos JavaScript e css - Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou tentando adaptar um modelo de layout que encontrei na net, no meu asp.net core, só que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.... Eu criei uma pasta Content na raiz do projeto e dentro dela tenho as subpastas com arquivos css e javascript. Eu já tentei referenciar e todas as formas, só que não está funcionando:

```js
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/animsition/animsition.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/asscrollable/asScrollable.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/switchery/switchery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/intro-js/introjs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/slidepanel/slidePanel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/chartist/chartist.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/global/vendor/chartist-plugin-tooltip/chartist-plugin-tooltip.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/examples/css/dashboard/v1.css">
```

Já tentei usar ~/, mas tb não funciona. Alguém sabe me ajudar?

Vou postar um print do projeto mostrando os caminhos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua pasta Content deveria estar dentro da wwwroot, as talvez você consiga referenciar os arquivos substituindo `../../` por `/`

Comment: Eu movi a pasta Content para dentro de wwwRoot, mas quando eu estarto a página fica em branco.. Não carrega nada... Já tentei usar ~/, /, mas não funcionou...

Comment: Qualquer coisa, coloquei no ondrive o projeto.. Se desejar dar uma olhada: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar isso `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` antes do `</body> </html>` no final da página.

Comment: Obrigado João Paulo!